# Queueing Methods With Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I am building a game simulator that has hundreds of micro steps like the following. They each perform a unique task, but I left out the implementation details for the sake of brevity.

```
public class Sim {

    static void phase() {
        phaseIn();
        phaseOut();
    }

    static void untap() {
    }

    static void upkeep() {
    }

    static void draw() {
    }

    ...
}
```

A `Turn` usually involves executing steps sequentially, but there are times when a special effect may cause the sequence to change. For example, I may be required to repeat a step twice, skip a step, or rearrange the order of the steps. These actions are all special cases, as the turn typically just occurs in order from start to finish.

For example, the following series of events represents my normal turn.

**... >** `upkeep()` **>** `draw()` **>** `preCombatMain()` **> ...**

Now, I play something that requires me to repeat my draw step. I need my turn to look like this:

**... >** `upkeep()` **>** `draw()` **>** `draw()` **>** `preCombatMain()` **> ...**

The steps of a turn are methods, and I do not know how to enqueue or dequeue methods. I know that Java 8 has method references, but the feature is relatively new. I have been unable to apply [existing tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to what I am trying to accomplish. I got as far as `Sim::untap`, but I have no idea how to assign it, invoke it, etc. **How do I queue methods in Java 8**, or otherwise call methods in an order determined at run-time by the choices a player makes?

*Note: I realize that my inability to understand may be due to a fundamental design flaw. I have never taken a game design course, I am completely open to criticism, and I will change my design if it is flawed. That said, the question is not to be misconstrued as "Please recommend a design pattern." I considered an alternate design, where I "number" each step in a massive switch statement, queue "numbers", and repeatedly switch on the front of the queue, but that seemed like a poor plan (in my opinion).*

Comment: Why are you using Java 8 for a game? If you plan to distribute it, it's going to take the market awhile to adopt. Java 7 was released years ago and still isn't the standard. If you use Java 8 specific features, you may miss part of the market.

Comment: @DeadChex This is not even a distributable product. I would be breaking copyright law if I did. I am programming the game for fun and to improve my understanding of the rules, which are fairly comprehensive. If I happen to complete it, then my friends and I get to practice for free.

Comment: @DeadChex Worst-case you just bundle the JRE anyways.

Comment: If it's just a matter of queueing method calls, you can just use a `Queue<Runnable>` and implement each step as a class that implements `Runnable`.  But I suspect that a plain queue-based design won't be flexible enough to handle all the things that might happen in the game, and the implied "real" question of how to implement M:TG in Java is probably too broad for a StackOverflow question.

Comment: @TomG can the JRE8 run on most today's platforms?

Comment: @DeadChex The platforms for which JDKs and JREs exist are listed here: https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

Comment: @Wyzard I did not intend to ask how to implement M:tG in Java. I intended to ask *"How do I queue a series of methods in Java?"* If that question was not clear, please suggest an edit that would improve the clarity. I want the question to be useful to any future visitor who does not know how to queue a series of methods in Java. I went ahead and put the question I intended to ask in **bold**, to hopefully make it easier to understand.

Comment: @John, no, your question is clear enough.  I'm just pointing out there's a big difference in degree-of-complexity between what you're asking (queueing method calls) and what it sounds like you're trying to accomplish (M:tG).  You may find that a completely different design is needed, and I wanted to mention that, while acknowledging that alternate designs would be out-of-scope for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply want them to run sequentially, you can of course call them one after the other. If the order can change, an alternative is to use a queue of method references:

```
LinkedList<Runnable> queue = new LinkedList<>();
queue.add(Sim::upkeep);
queue.add(Sim::draw);
queue.add(Sim::preCombatMain);
queue.forEach(Runnable::run);
```

I was able to use a `LinkedList<Runnable>` because the signature of your methods is `void m()`. For other signatures you can use other types, for example:

- `void m()` use `Runnable`
- `T m()` use `Supplier<T>`
- `void m(T o)` use `Consumer<T>`
- `R m(T o)` use `Function<T, R>`

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. By *"queue methods"*, I meant *"place chunks of code in a first-in, first-out structure, such as a Queue"*. Still, I think you answered the question even without understanding. If you can put methods into a `List` as you demonstrated, then it would be trivial to put them into a `Queue`. If I get it to work in a Queue instead of a List, I'll come back and edit your question (if you don't mind), and award you the answer.

Comment: @John This answer doesn't put *methods* in a list, rather it puts Runnables that *call* methods in a list. And yes, you can do it with a queue.

Comment: `LinkedList` implements `Queue`. :)

Comment: @DavidConrad This answer was edited after I commented on it, and so it is now using a LinkedList instead of a List. I chose not to delete my original comment lest radiodef's comment be invalidated.

Comment: @John Note that the code as is does not use the queue characteristics of the list since it just applies a `forEach`. So an `ArrayList` would behave exactly the same way (which is what I used in my original answer before your edit). If you need to queue/dequeue then obviously it may make sense.

Comment: @assylias Good catch. The answer would definitely be improved if it behaved like an actual queue. I imagine the more correct way is something like `while(!queue.isEmpty()) {queue.remove()::run}` where `remove()` always grabs the front of the queue, but I don't have a Java IDE at work to test.

Comment: @John Mutating the data structure on which the stream is based while using that stream is not recommended. You could just use a normal loop: `while(!queue.isEmpty()) queue.poll().run();`.

Comment: @assylias I didn't realize that `::` created a stream (still learning Java 8). Also, thank you for pointing out that `poll()` is an alternative to `remove()`. `poll()` looks to be more appropriate when the queue is expected to occasionally be empty, whereas `remove()` looks more appropriate when the queue should never be empty.

Comment: @John `::` does not create a stream, it is only a method reference. My comment about stream was in the context of the code in the answer. However you can't use a `::` in `queue.remove()::run`, it would not compile.

Comment: @John Ah, I see. I wasn't aware of the edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use polymorphism. Define an interface for the step:

```
interface Step {
  void process();
}
```

Then define each step by implementing it:

```
class UpkeepStep implements Step {
  void process() { ... }
}
```

Now you can put all your steps in an array, shuffle it, if needed, and execute all steps, like this:

```
for (Step step : steps) {
  step.process();
}
```

An alternative approach that may run faster, is to generate code that contains the method calls, compile it and load the class. However, it gives you only better performance if the step does not take much runtime compared to the method call overhead and if you execute each generated piece of code a lot, so the JIT will optimize it.